# How to call a function onclick from external JS - Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call function from exteral javascript on click but I still get a message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Widget is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

---

This is how my function looks:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          //code here
      function Widget() {
            $("div[data-pin]").each(function() {
              //code here
            });
      }
      Widget()
});
```

---

This is how I am trying to call the function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
      $(".button").one('click', function(){
        $(".div-inner").append("<div style='background: #fff;' data-pin></div>");
        $.getScript(window.location.origin + "/jquery.js", function() {
            $.getScript(window.location.origin + "/function.Widget.js", function() {
                Widget();
        });
        });
      });
});
```

Comment: Did you include that external java script in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the function outside of `jQuery()` or `$()` so it is declared in the global scope and accessible from all the scopes.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      //code here
      Widget()
});

function Widget() {
    jQuery("div[data-pin]").each(function() {
       //code here
    });
}
```

Comment: `$` will be undefined in `Widget()` if OP is using noConflict(), as e.g in wordpress

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, you're absolutely right! OP should be aware of this, but WordPress isn't tagged in the question, but from the code I see that he's passing $ as reference when calling `ready()`. So, that could be a clue he's in WordPress environment.

Comment: Thank you @Adam. It's Joomla. I moved the function outside the `jQuery()`. Error no longer occurs. But now function isn't showing onclick. I get the empty div `<div style='background: #fff;' data-pin></div>`. where it should be `<div style='background: #fff;' data-pin>code from Widget() function</div>`

Comment: Can you post your full code then? You might variables that aren't accessible in the `Widget()` scope

Comment: Here is the working fiddle @AdamAzad: http://jsfiddle.net/JakubSkowronski/c7s8dra8/15 it also works on my website  but I still get the message "Uncaught ReferenceError: Widget is not defined" in console.

Comment: The console didn't catch any reference errors in the jsFiddle, on your website though, you might have that function being called some where else. Would you like to link me to your website?